# Instagram Basic Display API - Not shown all media data

Tags: instagram

Hola!

I'm using Instagram Basic Display API to show Posts, Reals & Videos on our website via User Token Generator (Instagram Test Users).

GET Request is:

`https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=account_type,username,media&access_token={access_token}`

Version of IG API is v17.0.

I'm getting successfully media data but only five of them (I didn't find any formula between them, why these five media).

```
{
   "account_type": "BUSINESS",
   "username": "crazykarts.team",
   "media": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": {number}
         },
         {
            "id": {number}
         },
         {
            "id": {number}
         },
         {
            "id": {number}
         },
         {
            "id": {number}
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "cursors": {
            "before": {string},
            "after": {string}
         }
      }
   },
   "id": {number}
}
```

Of course, same data I'm getting on URL for media directly:

`https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=media_url,caption,permalink,media_type,thumbnail_url&access_token={access_token}`

I tried to completely remove App from Developer Facebook Tool, I changed account type from MEDIA_CREATOR to PERSONAL or BUSINESS, I double checked privacy settings, I didn't find anything. I also tried to add `&limit=1` parameter, pagination was working correctly but only for those 5 data. The most weird thing is that around week ago it works fine and I was getting all media data.

I don't have any limitation errors, profile is public, everything is shown, nothing hidden.

**EDIT:**
I found that all media data which have collaboration (with my personal account for example) accepted are not shown. Is there way how to make it works?

Do u have someone same experience?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you added `business_management` permission and generated a new user access token?

Comment: Nope. I don’t need to or at least based on my understanding. For only viewing posts, etc. is enough to generate access token for specific Account and that’s it. Application couldn’t be reviewed, approved and so on. Or I misunderstood something? Fyi: I edited my question with new stuff.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a new known issue for the instagram basic display. See links bellow.

https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/136553299510110/
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1941620312886486/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Standalone answers": However useful the reference, links on Stack Overflow are to provide context but not be the answer themselves.
Please summarize the issue in your post. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance.